# Rails development environment caching views when running on VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I'm using Rails 7.  I edit the files using Sublime Text on Windows 10.  I have shared the folder where these files are located.

The Rails environment runs inside an Ubuntu Server VM using virtualbox.  I use /etc/fstab to mount the cifs share containing the code base in Ubuntu.  I have read and have all of these settings in development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store

config.public_file_server.headers = {
'Cache-Control' => "no-cache"
}
```

I access the development website through a VirtualBox host only network (i.e. 192.168.56.101:3000) using Firefox.  I was having some trouble with files not update upon refresh, leading to some strange behavior.  For anything other than views (controllers, models..etc) it seems to be working fine.

However, I'm now operating on the view templates and they are simply not updating, sometimes through many reloads of the page.

I have tried to make sure firefox is not caching them.  Open the developer toolbar and disable HTTP caching.

I just opened Edge to see if it changes anything, and what do you know...even it's loading the old version of the view (without my changes).  So Rails must be caching them, right?  I did comment out the following lines:

```
# config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
# config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Something tells me there's an issue maybe with listen and the cifs share...so I have tried uncommenting out the above config line in development.rb...

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Supposedly this makes the listen gem use polling instead.

It still doesn't reload the views when I change them.

--UPDATE--  It seems to be an issue with the samba share (regarding the listen gem?)

Learned that file_watcher only works if reload_classes_only_on_change is enabled:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
OR
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

I moved the code base onto the Ubuntu VM in the home directory.  A.) it's faster.  B.) The views update properly when I used nano to change a view.html.erb

I setup a samba share on Ubuntu and connect to it from the windows host, so I can still use sublime text.  Had to add this line to my global .git_config under C:\Users[My User]

```
[safe]
 directory = %(prefix)///192.168.56.101/[VM_shared_folder]/[My App]
```

%(prefix) is literal, replace the rest with your setup

Hope this helps.